# VB.net show multiple instances of a EXTERNAL program

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, process, count

Right now I have the following code that SHOULD show the number of instances open on load event

```
Class MainWindow 

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        Dim processCount As Integer = Process.GetProcessesByName("WinWord").Count()

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} Instances Running", processCount.ToString()))
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, if I run the program with 2 instances of Word, it only shows 1. Could this be due to how Windows 8/7 deal with instances? in Task manager I see the process (Microsoft Word (32-bit) (2)), which to me would mean 2 instances of word are open, right?!?!

So what is wrong with my code? If your example is in C#, this is fine!

Comment: I even tried this   Dim instances() As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD")
            For Each instance As System.Diagnostics.Process In instances  InstanceCount = +1
            Next  . In which if I have 2 instances of WinWord, it still only shows 1.
               

            TextBlock1.Text = InstanceCount

Comment: I ran your code/scenario and don't encounter a problem. I get 2, even played with timing, starting a new process while running, GetProcessesByName definitely re-queries what's currently running. Is there something else your the rest of your code's doing or is this wrapped in something that may cause such behavior?

Comment: Hmm nope. Just running it from a load event. See updated code above. I am running Windows 8. Could this be the reason. Let me try to run other programs and see how many instances I see.

Comment: @ Denis. It might be the WinWord process. Tried Putty as the process, opened two instance, told me I had two instances, so that works. Hmmm I don't need to find out how many instances of the process WinWord, but I do wonder WHY its only telling me 1 instance of WinWord process is open, when its really 2?  Yet, if I can't find the answer, eh its fine. I'm just curious.

Comment: I ran your code on Server2008, maybe there is something funky with win8, weird! It'd be curious which WINWORD's instance process id you get..

Comment: I uploaded a screen shot of Task Manager. Lookly what I found.. two separate instances of putty with 2 PIDs and a instance of WinWord with a 2 next to it and 1 PID. http://s8.postimg.org/ihq61h4dx/process_multiinstance1.png

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Denis the code below works with other processes to see how many instances of a program are open, but it seems that Window's 8 only opens one process of WinWord and puts it under one PID, even if you open more than 1 instance.

```
Class MainWindow 

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
        Dim processCount As Integer = Process.GetProcessesByName("WinWord").Count()

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0} Instances Running", processCount.ToString()))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score -1):

If you change "WINWORD" to "WinWord" that may help you out.  Try to match exactly the process name in your .GetProcessByName.  Other than that, it may be Windows only returns one instance on the .count call there.  In that case, you can get instances of a program name, and assign it to your own count (variable) to get the desired results.